# Parse a nested Json

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have tried to parse this Json response but it seems like part of the Json is sent in some different format so when trying to parse the "Pricing" field under the "PREVIOUS_CONFIRMED_RESERVATION_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE" which is under "sessionAttributes" the result is undefined though other fields outside the "sessionAttributes" are accessible.

This is the Json file:

```
 {
"dialogState":"Fulfilled","intentName":"***","message":"Thank you....","messageFormat":"PlainText","responseCard":null,
    "sessionAttributes":{"PREVIOUS_CONFIRMED_RESERVATION_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE":
    "{\"ReservationType\":\"Main\",\"Pricing\":\"2000\",\"DP\":\"wedding\"}",


    "lastConfirmedReservation":"{\"ReservationType\":\"Shape\",\"Shape\":\"Round\"}"}
,"slotToElicit":null,
"slots":{"Shape":"Round"}
}
```

This is what I am trying to access after fetching this Json response:

```
await fetch(
      '****',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
      //**** some headers
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ inputText: clientMessage })
      }
    )
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(r => {
          pricing = r.sessionAttributes.PREVIOUS_CONFIRMED_RESERVATION_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE.Pricing;
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `PREVIOUS_CONFIRMED_RESERVATION_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE` field is a string, so you should convert it to JSON with [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), before accessing to `Pricing`.

```
pricing = JSON.parse(r.sessionAttributes.PREVIOUS_CONFIRMED_RESERVATION_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE).Pricing;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PREVIOUS_CONFIRMED_RESERVATION_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE  is a JSON string so you need to parse it again:

```js
const data = {
  "dialogState": "Fulfilled",
  "intentName": "***",
  "message": "Thank you....",
  "messageFormat": "PlainText",
  "responseCard": null,
  "sessionAttributes": {
    "PREVIOUS_CONFIRMED_RESERVATION_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE": "{\"ReservationType\":\"Main\",\"Pricing\":\"2000\",\"DP\":\"wedding\"}",


    "lastConfirmedReservation": "{\"ReservationType\":\"Shape\",\"Shape\":\"Round\"}"
  },
  "slotToElicit": null,
  "slots": {
    "Shape": "Round"
  }
};

console.log(JSON.parse(data.sessionAttributes.PREVIOUS_CONFIRMED_RESERVATION_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE).Pricing);
```

Then in your case:

```
pricing = JSON.parse(r.sessionAttributes.PREVIOUS_CONFIRMED_RESERVATION_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE).Pricing;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should parse PREVIOUS_CONFIRMED_RESERVATION_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE in  response

```
await fetch(
      '****',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
      //**** some headers
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ inputText: clientMessage })
      }
    )
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(r => {
          const responseData =  JSON.parse(r.sessionAttributes.PREVIOUS_CONFIRMED_RESERVATION_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE)
          const pricing = responseData.Pricing;
      });
```